# different brainpoolP521r1 parameters for flexiProvider. Why?

Tags: java, elliptic-curve

I am trying to generate ECC public private key pairs using flexiProvider. I have noticed that values for parameters like p and q are different in brainpoolP521r1 of flexiProvider than those which are specified in many sites. Values specified are Q= AADD.... but what I get is Q=8948... Any idea why flexiProvider does not use specified values and whether having different values is affectes security. I am new to ECC. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe you are printing the values out in decimal rather than hex.

Comment: Thanks a million..:) I was printing values in decimal.

Answer (score 0):

From OP:

> I was printing values in decimal